# I tried to install Kubuntu 22.10 from a USB on b550 and Creative AE-7 sound card but Kubuntu didn't start

Tags: kubuntu, alsa, soundcard

I tried Kubuntu 22.10. When the Creative AE-7 sound card was installed the Linux installation didn't start. I uninstalled the sound card and wow! Linux was installing and it simply worked. I installed the Creative AE-7 sound card on Intel p8z77v Core i5 3550, inserted a USB flash drive with Kubuntu and the Kubuntu  installation didn't start.

Hardware error:

```
cpu soft lockup 
cpu hard lockup
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/S2ms5bh4bqaZUmEMA